# How do I avoid version conflicts using NServiceBus with Castle Windsor WcfFacility?

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus, castle, wcffacility

It appears the NServiceBus is built against Castle Windsor 2.0.0.0, whilst the WcfFacility needs to be built against 2.5.2.

Is there any way I can run both NServiceBus and the WcfFacility in the same project? We're developing a network service that will use both WCF and NServiceBus to communicate with other components and having endless problems with Windsor version conflicts.

Comment: I think you need to upgrade NServiceBus or recompile it yourself. I doubt simple assembly version redirect will do - there are some significant changes between 2.0 and 2.5 of Windsor

Comment: Could you get away with using the OOTB wcf integration for NSB only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John Simons (member of the Castle team) is currently working with the NServiceBus team to upgrade Windsor in NServiceBus: https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/pull/28

So go and jump into the discussion, test John's fork, etc.